# Different styling in a line in wordprocessing with opxnxml in c#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I have used codes below to apply two different character style to the two runs of one paragraph:

```
            Paragraph heading = new Paragraph();
            ParagraphProperties heading_pPr = new ParagraphProperties();
            heading.Append(heading_pPr);

            Run Run1 = new Run() { RsidRunProperties = "009531B2" };
            Text Text_Run1 = new Text("THIS IS TEST RUN 1");
            Run1.Append(Text_Run1);
            RunProperties rpr_Run1 = new RunProperties();
            rpr_Run1.RunStyle = new RunStyle() { Val = "CharacterStyle1" };

            Run Run2 = new Run();
            RunProperties rpr_Run2 = new RunProperties();
            rpr_Run2.RunStyle = new RunStyle() { Val = "CharacterStyle2" };
            Text text_Run2 = new Text("THIS IS TEST RUN 2");
            Run2.Append(text_Run2);

            heading.Append(Run1);
            heading.Append(Run2);
            body.Append(heading);
```

But after running the code, In the word file these runs gets the **Normal** style.
I can apply paragraph style to the paragraph but i can't apply character style to run,Where is wrong in my code?

*In Conclusion:*

How can i apply character style to a run and how to have a paragraph with different styling Run?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the formatting for the paragraph in its properties section otherwise it's going to fallback to the document's default which in this case is `Normal`. This might also happen if your custom styles are not saved to the styles part of the document.

Change your code to:

```
Paragraph heading = new Paragraph();
ParagraphProperties heading_pPr = new ParagraphProperties();
heading.Append(heading_pPr);
ParagraphMarkRunProperties headingParagraphMarkRunProperties = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
RunStyle runStyle1 = new RunStyle(){ Val = "CharacterStyle1" };

headingParagraphMarkRunProperties.Append(runStyle1);
heading_pPr.Append(headingParagraphMarkRunProperties);
```

This will enable your paragraph to adopt your custom formatting. You still need to apply individual styles to the `run` elements to change it's formatting as you correctly did in your rest of the code.